# Paths with ../ does not work on win XP and Qt

Tags: qt, file-io, windows-xp

I have an application with executable that resides in somwhere/appDir/bin. I want it to open file that is in somwhere/appDir/data.  It works fine on Win7, Win8 and Vista, but fails on XP. My code is:

```
QString dirPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QFile* src;    
src = new QFile(dirPath + "/../data/file.txt");
qDebug()<<src->exists();
```

App crashes when execution gets to `src->exists()`. When there are no `..` in the path everything works fine. Why? Is there any other way to get to the parent directory other than stripping directory name from path string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove last directory name from dirPath.

```
 QStringList dirPathSplitted = dirPath.split("/");
 dirPathSplitted.removeLast();
 QString dirPath = dirPathSplitted.join("/");
 src = new QFile(dirPath + "/data/file.txt");
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it might work. If it's not working only on WinXP it might be a bug. You might consider reporting it. But if above works on XP, it should work on others too.